# Install Oracle 11gR2 driver for Node.js 0.10.20

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux, installation

I want to connect Oracle 11gR2 and Node.js 0.10.20. I use [this package](https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-oracle) but I don't understand this part of installation process. Can you explain it to me?

```sh
# Replace /opt/instantclient_11_2/ with wherever you extracted the Basic Lite files to
echo '/opt/instantclient_11_2/' | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle_instant_client.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have to include Oracle instant client libraries into the database used by Linux dynamic linker when it has to resolve run time bindings.

Instructions tells you to create new .conf file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ directory with the Oracle instant client libraries directory. And then you have to run `ldconfig` with root permissions so that it will create new database with the Oracle instant client libraries included.

Example from one of our servers:

```
# cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf
/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/
```

.conf file name does not matter.

Comment: i do it , now what should i do to install packages ?

Comment: You have to download and install Oracle instant client packages from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html

Comment: thanks . i download oracle instantclient and sdk . i insatll them on /opt/instantclient . what should i do ofter that ? which node packages are install ? thanks about your answers